# logic Accounting trick

Tags: arithmetic

Tom went to shop with a fake \$1000 for shopping.He bought items worth \$800 from shopkeeper A A.The shopkeeper had no change so he went to borrow from shopkeeper B. He came back and gave Tom his change.Shopkeeper B realized that shopkeeper A had given him a fake \$1000 note and went back for his money and was given a valid \$1000 note.

Question: 
How much did shopkeeper A lose ?

Comment: Hi Willie, welcome to MSE! Please tell us what you've tried so far, or what exactly it is about the question that you're finding difficult.  Either add this information to your question by clicking the [edit] button or put it in a comment.

Comment: I am coming up with 1000 but everybody else is getting 1200. I dont see the 1200

Comment: @Willie please edit your question and explain there how you come up with 1000

Comment: I divided the question into four parts and kept my focus on shopkeeper A. Then on every exchange I calculated his gain or loss having in mind that he got a fake bill.  1. He gets a fake 1000 and gives 800 worth of goods So -800 2. He gives Shopkeeper B a fake 1000 and gets a real one so +1000. 3. He gives Tom 200 so -200.4. shopkeeper B comes for his 1000 so A loses -1000. If you add 1 through 4 you end up with -1000.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the loss is exactly \$1000, assuming of course that we ignore the profit made by selling \$800 worth of goods.

At the start, A had a valid \$1000 bill and \$800 of goods.  At the end, she had 
no \$1000 bill, \$800 in small-bill change obtained from B, and none of those goods.  The \$800 change balances the \$800 in goods, so the net loss is the valid \$1000 bill.

Comment: Thanks. Hard to convince my friends

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is \$1200. This is because Shopkeeper A loses \$800 to Tom. He exchanges with Shopkeeper B and gives Tom \$200 which means that Tom walked out with \$800 worth of items and \$200. Shpkpr B collects the remaining \$800 plus \$200 from Shpkpr A. 1000+200=1200